# Не отображается выбранный элемент во Spinner'е

Tags: android, android-spinner

Не отображается выбранный элемент во Spinner'е
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У вас просто цвет текста белый, вот и не видно:)

Comment: Банально стили, скорее всего, так выставлены, либо параметр цвета в xml установлен в белый

Comment: ну тут нужно смотреть уже конкретней